# How to redirect to new page using user-id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this button to open new page for each user details

```
 <div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#/customer-app.html/{{customer.input.phoneid}}" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i></a>
  <a href="#/customer-transaction.html" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i></a>
 </div>
```

My requirement is that if user click the first button it will redirect to each customer page using `customer-app.html` link. I tried to use `{{customer.input.phoneid}}` because in my `customer-app.html` i am using `input.phoneid` for the search button. but it doesn't work as i want.

```
<form name="searchForm" ng-submit="refresh()">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id=phoneid" ng-model="input.phoneid" ng-trim="true">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1" ng-click="refresh()">Search</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

[image]

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("dashboard.html");

$stateProvider.state('customer-app', {
        url: "/customer-app.html?phoneid&page",
        templateUrl: 'views/customer-app/customer-app.html?_=' + app.version,
        controller: 'customer-app'
    })
```

i have another page that use `#app-edit.html/{{app._id}}` that perfectly work. but in this page i want to use phone id in the `customer-app` page

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "/customer-app/:id"
```

**Controller Function**

```
  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state){
    $scope.redirect= function (id) {
       $state.go('state', {id : id});
    }
    //here you can get the parameter
}]);
```

**Another Controller**

```
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams){
    //$stateParams.id        
        //here you can get the parameter
}]);
```

Comment: i have another page that use `#app-edit.html/{{app._id}}` that perfectly work. but in this page i want to use phone id in the `customer-app` page

Comment: ues $stateParams to get that id.

Comment: can u provide me example?

Comment: see this http://tommytan.azurewebsites.net/angularjs-sending-data-between-states/